# Deploying local Jekyll blog to github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am having difficulty getting my Jekyll blog to display on gh pages the same way that it is displaying locally. It seems that the css and js is not loading because what I am getting is bare text/links yet the links don't work.

I have even tried deploying the _site folder directly into my host via FileZilla and I am getting the same exact problem.

Comment: *"I have even tried deploying the _site folder directly into my host via FileZilla and I am getting the same exact problem."* GitHub Pages don't work that way. Are you talking about a different host? Please edit your question to show [some relevant code](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your site is hosted at `yourname.github.io/repositoryname` ?

In `_config.yml`, simply set `baseurl: /repositoryname`.

Call assets like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/css/style.css" | prepend: site.baseurl }}">
```

or

```
<script src="{{site.baseurl}}/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```